# Angular-Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/v0/dataservice/cluster/clusters from localhost:4300 to http://localhost:30510 (ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: node.js, angular, proxy, angular-cli

I am working on Angular 6 application. I was try to run `npm audit fix` and `npm audit fix --force` to fix vulnerabilities. After that My application is not compile and working. So I delete package-lock.json, node modules folder and take old package.json file and install npm again.
Somehow I manage to compile and run the application but where I have api calls I am getting this error in browser
[image]

And in the terminal:
[image]

First time I am facing this type of issue So I have no idea about how to fix it.
Here is my `proxy.config.json` file where I found http://localhost:30510 url

```
{
    "/api/v0/dataservice/*" : {
      "target" : "http://localhost:30510",
      "secure" : false,
      "logLevel" : "debug"
    }
  }
```

I have try below solutions:

1. Replace `localhost` with `[::1]`
2. try to add

   headers: {
   "Connection": "keep-alive"
   }
3. add `"changeOrigin": true`
   but not work any above solution

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below proxy configuration:

```
{
        "/api/v0/dataservice/*": {
                "target": "http://localhost:5000",
                "secure": false,
                "changeOrigin": true,
                "pathRewrite": {"^/api/v0/dataservice" : "/api/v0/dataservice"}
        }
}
```

Also please check whether the backend server is currently working. This error generally occurs when the backend server is not up.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to double check is that you correctly defined your proxy in your `angular.json` file. I often forget to do this and then get this error:

```json
...
"serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
        "browserTarget": "project-name:build",
        "proxyConfig": "proxy.config.json"
    },
...
```